# When I access my page I have a 403 Forbidden error LiteSpeed Web Server

Tags: php, webserver, wordpress

I'm trying to install Wordpress using OpenLiteSpeed webserver. Wordpress is installed in `/usr/local/lsws/Liveragi/html/{wordpress files}`.

When I access the page using HTTP the page has a "404 Not Found" error and with HTTPS the page is throwing a "403 Forbidden" error. I have PHP latest version installed and the web panel works well.

If I put an `.html` file it works but if it is PHP, I get "403 Forbidden".

Hope someone has the solution to this. Thanks.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu Server latest version

Answer (score 0):

If a visitor hits the LiteSpeed WordPress Protection feature with over-limit connections, it may trigger a 403 error.

Source: [403 Error](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cp/cpanel/403-error/#:%7E:text=Generally%2C%20it%20is%20not%20LiteSpeed,see%20if%20the%20error%20continues.)

Additional knowledge: [403 forbidden](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/threads/solved-403-forbidden.6189/)

Really worth to read: [Brute Force Attack Protection](https://blog.litespeedtech.com/2017/12/20/wpw-brute-force-attack-protection/)

This describes how to enable it, but the same way you can disable it and check:
[WordPress Brute Force Attack Protection](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:lslb:wordpress-protection)

Comment: Hello @Sysadmin! I don't think the error comes from Wordpress but from the OpenLiteSpeed server. If I change permissions and I put, for example, 777 I visit the page and I see "404 error". I hope this give some more context.

Comment: Did you read all what I provided? Seems not. Can you check the log from litespeed in /var/log ? It will tell you what is the reason. Admin should read the log - this is crucial.